# Can you test the latest version of Firefox (52 as of now) using Webdriver.io?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I can see that Webdriver.io only supports Selenium 2, and the latest FF is using Selenium 3, so is there any work around to use Webdriver.io for the latest FF? Is Webdriver.io planning to support Selenium 3 anytime soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of firefox needed **gecko driver** to launch, for this you have to download **geckodriver.exe**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the support for selenium 3, but I am using latest version of ff, 52.0.1 - x64 & it is working fine with my tests. I am using selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1